# Как записать значение в массив при Foreach

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$myArray = [
 0 => [
  id => 1,
  title => 'title1'
 ],
 1 => [
  id => 2,
  title => 'title2'
 ],
 2 => [
  id => 3,
  title => 'title3'
 ],
 3 => [
  id => 4,
  title => 'title4'
 ]
];
```

Теперь есть функция в которую я передаю значение массива и полученное значение от функции нужно записать в этот же массив.

Как это сделать через foreach, при переборе массива добавлять в массив новое значение?

```
foreach ($myArray as $item)
{
 $item[]['funcResult'] = myFunc($item['id']);
}
```

Если записать так, то получится массив:

```
$myArray = [
 0 => [
  id => 1,
  title => 'title1'
 ],
 1 => [
  id => 2,
  title => 'title2'
 ],
 2 => [
  id => 3,
  title => 'title3'
 ],
 3 => [
  id => 4,
  title => 'title4'
 ]
4 => 
['funcResult' => '5'],
];
```

А нужно чтобы добавило всем элементам, типа так:

```
$myArray = [
 0 => [
  id => 1,
  title => 'title1',
'funcResult' => '2'
 ],
 1 => [
  id => 2,
  title => 'title2',
'funcResult' => '3'
 ],
 2 => [
  id => 3,
  title => 'title3',
'funcResult' => '1'
 ],
 3 => [
  id => 4,
  title => 'title4',
'funcResult' => '5'
 ]

];
```

Решил задачу через for, но есть ли вариант через foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не приведен код функции myfunc() поэтому так:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $item)
{
 $myArray[$key]['funcResult'] = $item['id'];
}
unset($key);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => title1
            [funcResult] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => title2
            [funcResult] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => title3
            [funcResult] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => title4
            [funcResult] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: работающий пример http://ideone.com/thUl0L

Answer (score 1):

Можно передать значение по ссылке с помощью "&":

```
foreach($array as &$item){
   $item['any'] = true;
}
```

Comment: вы мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548920/7161) повторили, с сокращениями? =)

Comment: @Sergiks, не заметил Ваш ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $item)
{
    $myArray[$key]['funcResult'] = myFunc($item['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно [передавать по ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php) очередной элемент, и менять его:

```
foreach( $myArray as &$item) {
    $item['funcResult'] = myFunc( $item['id']);
}
unset( $item);
```

Рабочий [**пример**](http://ideone.com/4fwSxO), где в ф-ии значение `id` умножается на 10.

**Результат:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => title1
            [funcResult] => 10
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => title2
            [funcResult] => 20
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => title3
            [funcResult] => 30
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => title4
            [funcResult] => 40
        )
)
```